# Upgrade or replace hardware

Tags: desktop, upgrade

My father is a 75yo retiree and an active photographer using photoshop,lightroom and some office tasks. Around 10 years ago we built a desktop with following specs which is now severely impacting performance:

Windows 7 Home Premium
CPU: i7 - 8 core 2.8GHz
RAM: 8GB, 1333MHz
Motherboard: Intel MB, Model Nr, DP55WB
Storage:
Main OS                                                           C:           1TB        88% free
Backup                                               B:           2TB        97% free
Data                                                   D:           2TB        0% free
Verbatim (external)                        I:             2TB        18% free

My question, should we upgrade or replace with a budget of $1500 given that he will likely wind down activity of this nature within the next 10 years? He mightbe relatively old but still wants performance;)
Any thoughts on target specs/components for this budget?
Thank you

Comment: 10 years is a long time in computer terms, But, if it has a mechanical hard drive for the OS, then a SSD (and probably another 8gb of Ram? (check the max commit)) could give it a new lease of life (Likely for under 100$). Personally, I would turn it into a NAS using TrueNas or Unraid and go for a new PC as you would need a new Motherboard, Processor, Power supply (and Graphics Card) if replacing parts, and that's most of the cost in a PC anyway.

Comment: Editing your question to include what country you're in may help folks advising you. A good start might be https://pcpartpicker.com or pcbuilder.net to see what level machine is likely with $1500 (Also, running a userbenchmark.com test might help you identify the current bottleneck, and decide the balance between money spent on CPU and GPU, keeping in mind the photo editing usage.